# Block diagram child node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts

I'm just trying to make any block diagram using LaTeX, but i get into a trouble that I don't know how to make child of a node,

[image]

All I want is to move the box named "Antrian" into the red position, and make the two boxes below it as its child node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
    text width=22mm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (operasional) {Operasional};
    \node [block, right of=operasional, node distance = 3cm] (proses) {Proses};

    \node[block, right of= proses, node distance = 3cm] (antrian){Antrian};
    \node[block, below of= antrian] (kasir){Jumlah kasir yang beroperasi};
    \node[block, right of=kasir, node distance = 3cm](kedatangan){Rata-rata tingkat kedatangan};
    \coordinate[below = of $(kasir.south)!0.5!(kedatangan.south)$](temp1);
    \node[block, below of = temp1, node distance =3cm] (kinerja) {Kinerja};
    \node[block,left of= kinerja, node distance = 3cm](pelayanan){Pelayanan yang optimal};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (operasional) -- (proses);
    \path[line] (proses) -- (antrian);
    \path [line] (antrian.south) -| (kasir);
    \path [line] (antrian.south) -| (kedatangan);
    \path [line] (kinerja) -- (pelayanan);
    \draw   (kasir.south) |- (temp1) -| (kedatangan);
    \draw[-Latex]   (temp1) -- (kinerja);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I really need your help, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You are loading but not using `positioning`. I also replaced `\tikzstyle` by the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, arrows.meta, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    % Define block styles
    \tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, 
    text width=22mm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'}}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (operasional) {Operasional};
    \node [block, right=of operasional] (proses) {Proses};

    \node[block, right=of  proses] (antrian){Antrian};
    \node[block, below left=of  antrian] (kasir){Jumlah kasir yang beroperasi};
    \node[block, below right=of antrian](kedatangan){Rata-rata tingkat kedatangan};
    \coordinate[below = of $(kasir.south)!0.5!(kedatangan.south)$](temp1);
    \node[block, below of = temp1, node distance =3cm] (kinerja) {Kinerja};
    \node[block,left=of  kinerja](pelayanan){Pelayanan yang optimal};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (operasional) -- (proses);
    \path[line] (proses) -- (antrian);
    \path [line] (antrian.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (kasir);
    \path [line] (antrian.south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (kedatangan);
    \path [line] (kinerja) -- (pelayanan);
    \draw   (kasir.south) |- (temp1) -| (kedatangan);
    \draw[-Latex]   (temp1) -- (kinerja);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SutMar Glad to hear! BTW, if the answer worked for you, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark left of it?